# JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance - Is this the right way to do things?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype, instantiation

If I declare the base prototype object outside the constructor for an object, all created objects are based on that single base object which is not suitable for my needs because I need more than one instance of the base object.

In short: Is this code correct? It works but I'm picky about having correct code.

Example:

```
function BaseObject()
{
    BaseObject.prototype.insertObject = function()…
    …
    … // Some other functions.
}

function Object1()
{
    Object1.prototype = new BaseObject();

    Object1.prototype.coolFunction = function()…
    …
    … // Same kind of pattern.
}

function Object2()
{
    Object2.prototype = new Object1();

    Object2.prototype.incredibleFunction = function()…
    …
    … // You get the idea.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, all the code that is currently inside your constructor functions should be outside of them. Right now you are reassigning those properties of the prototype every time someone creates a new object.

Finally, points of good-practice:

- You should always "fix" the `constructor` property of any derived prototypes. This is a quirk of JS inheritance; it gets overwritten. People rarely depend on the `constructor` property being correct, but sometimes they do, and it just feels wrong if you don't.
- `Object.create(Base.prototype)` is better than `new Base()` if you are working in browsers that support it, or using [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim). It only instantiates the object, instead of creating it, which is good since you don't need an actual copy of the object to perform prototypal inheritance.

This would all look like:

```
function BaseObject() { }

BaseObject.prototype.insertObject = function () { };

function Object1() { }

Object1.prototype = Object.create(BaseObject.prototype);
Object1.prototype.constructor = Object1;
Object1.prototype.coolFunction = function () { };

function Object2() { }

Object2.prototype = Object.create(Object1.prototype);
Object2.prototype.constructor = Object2;
Object2.prototype.incredibleFunction = function () { };
```

Comment: If I do `Object1.prototype = new BaseObject();` outside of the constructor, every object created from Object1 relies on that single instance of BaseObject. I need a way to create new instances of BaseObject.

Comment: That will still be the case even if you perform it inside the constructor. `Object1.prototype` is shared by every instance of `Object1`, so all you're doing every time you reassign it is making every instance of `Object1` rely on the same newly-constructed prototype `BaseObject`.

Comment: But when I do this in my actual code it works just like I need it to because every time the constructor gets called it sets the prototype on the object to be a newly created instance of `BaseObject`, and then I repeat that pattern and it works fine. There has just got to be a clean and correct way to do this.

Comment: It will work as you are doing it; it is just inefficient and unconventional ("wrong"). Also "sets the prototype on *the* object" is incorrect; it sets the prototype on *every* object.

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern:

```
function Base ( baseMember ) {
    this.baseMember = baseMember;
}

Base.prototype.baseFunc = function () {};

function Derived ( baseMember, derivedMember ) {
    Base.apply( this, arguments );   
    this.derivedMember = derivedMember;
}

Derived.prototype = Object.create( Base.prototype );
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;

Derived.prototype.derivedFunc = function () {};
```

It's ugly, I know...